# How to take a screenshot while running an event on android device using adb shell?

Tags: android, shell

I'm trying to make a simple batch file, which will send a long press or a swipe event to my android device. And during that time I need to take a screenshot. Ofc a screenshot could be taken manually, but I need to do that like 100 times. I've tried a code below and it didn't work. The screenshot would be taken after event is already done. If there is no way to accomplish that in batch, then can you give me any suggestion how I can do that in python.

```
adb shell input swipe 47 1414 47 1414 5000 | adb shell screencap -p /sdcard/screenshot.png  
adb pull /sdcard/screenshot.png "%UserProfile%\Desktop\Screenshots\screenshot.png"  
adb shell rm /sdcard/screenshot.png
```

Comment: Would it be possible to start capturing video, perform the swipe, and pull a frame from the video?

Comment: Well, I need screenshots as it is easy to work with them. Easy to edit and share. Thanks for suggestion .

Comment: "It didn't work." <-- You need to be more specific.

Comment: @fadden, any suggestions?